# Use LZF Compression instead GZIP with NginX

Tags: nginx, lzf

Is there a way to change the handler for compression from gzip to lzf in nginx ?

Actual config:

```
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_min_length     1024;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

can be it translated to  ?

```
lzf on;
..
..
```

Comment: What's the reason to do so? Which browser do support lzf?

Comment: ah, this is a good question, the idea is that lzf is better than gzip.

Comment: Better in what criteria? And does it matter in real life?

Comment: LZF is better in compression/uncompression speed, i.e. trade-off between bit lower compression, and much faster compression (5-10x), uncompression (2x-3x). Whether it is better for any given scenario depends on which one you want to conserve more, bandwidth (network, I/O), or CPU.